# Google sheets find from named range a specified date&time display description from that named range

Tags: google-sheets

I'm writing a schedule for my wife and I in Google Sheets that seemed to be working but is missing some of our scheduled meetings/appointments. A link to an exact copy is found [here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JINVcTPlfjPK1SPoTDC9eKhpYzmG6daq3umrBn_8TP0/edit#gid=0)

The idea is that within the "Event Scheduler" I can list in DATE | TIME | DESCRIPTION and it generates a UNIQUE ID using =V14&"|"&COUNTIF(V$14:V14,V14) and also generating a DATE&TIME using DATE&TIME format. I highlight each person (or animal)'s scheduled items in named ranges named "MolliesEvents", "AydensEvents" and "DogsEvents". I now go to the main page, "Daily + Weekly" and compared the current date TODAY() and the time in the E column to the DATE&TIME column of the "Event Scheduler" sheet. Weirdly, this works for some of the scheduled items. However, a significant minority is not captured by the code that I've used. Weirder still, when I compared manually the time in the "Event Scheduler" with the time and date on the "Daily + Weekly" page I get a positive result. However, when I attempt to automate this process it does not.

Answer (score 1):

You are losing events due to rounding.
For example, consider the event "Monday, March 22, 2021 11:30:00 Doctor calling".
In the 'Event Scheduler'!F18 cell is 442770.479166666666667.

In the 'Daily + Weekly'!F14 cell, you use `TODAY()&E14` = 442770.479166666666666 in the formula.

Due to the fact that 442770.479166666666667 does not equal 442770.479166666666666, this event does not hit the sheet. This also applies to other lost events.

Possible Solution.
Delete the 'Time Intervals' sheet and enter the time manually on the 'Daily + Weekly' sheet in column E.

Also, I would change the formula like this:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(MolliesEvents, MATCH(TODAY()&E14, 'Event Scheduler'!$F$14:$F$1000,0),3),"")` (this is in the F14, copy it to other cells).

Here's an [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16VDvcIlUav7xPtAX3_fhQaT2Nr17LnFUOvQ4qovgpVU/copy) of a spreadsheet that works well.

Comment: I’ll give this a go when I next can, thank you very much!